# I can't get key-value chaining (KVC) to work in Swift for compound dot paths

Tags: xcode, swift, kvc

Consider the following class, which can be executed in the Xcode Playground:

```
import Foundation
class MyClass : NSObject {

    var stringProperty:String
    var integerProperty:Int
    var linkedInstance:MyClass!

    init(String string:String, Int int:Int) {
        stringProperty = string
        integerProperty = int
    }
}
```

The following lines work as expected.

```
var myInstance = MyClass(String: "xxx", Int: 32)
myInstance.valueForKey("stringProperty")
myInstance.setValue(2, forKey: "integerProperty")
myInstance.valueForKey("integerProperty")

var anotherInstance = MyClass(String: "yyy", Int: 33)
myInstance.linkedInstance = anotherInstance
myInstance.linkedInstance.integerProperty = 2
```

However trying to access the value using KVC via a compound path,

```
myInstance.valueForKey("linkedInstance.integerProperty")
```

causess the error "Execution was interrupted, reason signal SIGABRT." I have not made any compound paths work with Swift, yet they work fine in Objective-C. Dose this have to do with optionals? Values for simple paths are returned wrapped.

Answer (score 2):

As soon as you change that last line to

```
myInstance.valueForKeyPath("linkedInstance.integerProperty")
```

your Playground will play a lot nicer with you.

The lesson is: Do not confuse `valueForKey:` with `valueForKeyPath:`! The expression `valueForKey("linkedInstance.integerProperty")` can never succeed in Swift or in Objective-C, because`"linkedInstance.integerProperty"` is *not* a key - it is a key path.

Comment: Agreed with the caveat that it *can* succeed in certain very specific cases. In particular, when applied to a dictionary which actually has a key `@"linkedInstance.integerProperty"`. Dictionaries translate `-valueForKey:` to `-objectForKey:`. I wouldn't bring it up, except that you said "never". :)

Comment: @KenThomases You know me, and you know perfectly well that I meant "never" given his particular arrangement of objects and properties. The point was: he says this worked in Objective-C. I'm saying: No it didn't - not the way you've written it.

Comment: Thank you, and yes it was simply a confusion between key and key paths.